# Existence of a non-measurable set

Tags: measure-theory

Question on Existence of a non-measurable set:

Let us consider a unit circle .We define a relation on the set of points on the circumference of a circle by $x\sim y \iff x-y\in \mathbb Q $.The equivalence relation will give rise to some disjoint equivalence classes.

we choose an element from each of these equivalence classes and form the set $E$ .My instructor asks me to show it is non-measurable.

Should I proceed by contradiction?If $E$ is measurable then we have two cases either $\mu^*(E)=0$ or $u^*(E)>0$.How to proceed now?

Comment: What does it mean that $x-y\in\mathbb Q$ for $x,y$ in the unit circle. Are you identifying the unit circle with $[0,2\pi)$?

Comment: Better to identify with $[0,1)$ perhaps.

Comment: The measure of the Circle is zero.https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1335656/what-is-the-lebesgue-measure-of-a-circle-in-mathbbr2. Hence it cannot have a non measurable subset...

Answer (score 2):

**HINT:** Show that the unit circle is a disjoint union of countable many translations of $E$, and conclude that either cases are impossible.

Answer (score 1):

The usual idea is to use the fact that rational translates of $E$ have the same outer measure as $E$. If $C$ is the circumference of the circle and $E$ is measurable you get 
$$\mu^*(C) = \sum_r \mu^*(E  + r)$$ where the sum is taken over an infinite set of rational numbers. If $\mu^*(E) = 0$ then so is the sum, and if $\mu^*(E) > 0$ then the sum is infinite. Neither of these is consistenct with $0 < \mu^*(C) < \infty$.

Comment: Why is $0<\mu ^*(C)<\infty$

Comment: suppose $y$ is a point on the cirumference then why it is that $y\in E+r$ for some $r>0$?\