# What is the probability that the point lies on the circumference of a (centered) circle of radius r/2 inside the circle with radius r?

Tags: probability, circles, area

A point is chosen at random inside a circle of radius $r$. Find the probability that the point lies on the circumference of a (centered) circle of radius $r/2$
inside the circle with radius $r$
?
What I tried was that I drew another circle of radius $r/2$ inside the circle of radius $r$. Dividing circumference of the circle (radius $r/2$) by the area of the circle (radius $r$) you get probability $1/r$. Is it correct?

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE. Take a look at [How to ask a good question at Math.SE](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question). To avoid downvotes and closing you should add your own efforts to the question by means of an edit (not a comment), and tell us where you got stuck.

Comment: Can you explain the problem more precisely (probability distribution?)? Also: What have you tried?

Comment: Unless your distribution has a singularity at the center of the circle, the probability of your random point coinciding with the center will always be zero.

Comment: English isn't my first language please help me frame the question in the correct way. Also it would be helpful if you could help me with the answer. What I did was that I drew another circle of radius r/2 in inside the circle of radius r. Dividing circumference of the circle (radius r/2) by the area of the circle (radius r) you get probability 1/r. Is it correct?

Comment: The question is still not clear: What do you mean by "the point is in the middle of the center of the circle and its circumference."? Is there a smaller circle inside the first circle? If you have a hard time explaining, could you provide a sketch?

Comment: I'm trying to find the probability of the point being exactly at the mid point of the radius r. So that the point is in the middle of the centre and it's circumference.

Comment: How do I add a picture. This is my first question and I don't know how to use this website.

Comment: Aha, so you want the probability that the point lies on the circumference of a (centered) circle of radius $r/2$ inside the circle with radius $r$?

Comment: Yes that's correct Dominik.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: The probability of hitting a 1-dimensional curve in a 2-dimensional space will (usually) be zero.

Assuming a regular distribution (in particular no deltas) on the circle of radius $r$, the probability of the random point lying exactly on the circumference of a circle of radius $r/2$ is zero. This is because the circumference has measure zero  (being a smooth one-dimensional curve of finite length in $\mathbb R^2$).

Further reading: See [What is the Lebesgue measure of a circle in $\mathbb{R}^2$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1335656/what-is-the-lebesgue-measure-of-a-circle-in-mathbbr2) and [Is the Lebesgue measure of the unit circle $0$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1996272/is-the-lebesgue-measure-of-the-unit-circle-0) for explanations why the boundary of a circle has zero Lebesgue measure.

Comment: Thank you Dominik. It was asked in an exam for highschool maths teaching job. It was asked for the circle of radius 2 and in the answer key they gave the answer 1/2. Which seemed impossible when I tried to visualise it.

Comment: Their answer is really odd...

Comment: Maybe the examiner didn't know much and tried to create a new question using the usual question: A point in a circle is selected at random. Calculate probability that point is closer to centre than circumference.